# What are my options for transitions between Linoleum and tile?

Tags: tile, linoleum

I just completed building a bathroom in the basement. The last piece is installing some sort of transition between ceramic tile bathroom floor and linoleum tile outside. The tile in the bathroom is about 1/2 to 5/8 inch higher than the linoleum. Linoleum is glued directly onto a concrete slab.
What are my options as far as transition pieces?

Comment: There are many products for this. They tend to made of wood, plastic and aluminum.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Could you be a bit more specific? Since it is the basement, I would prefer to stay away from wood (or other materials vulnerable to moisture).

Comment: Then an aluminum transition strip is likely in order. See an answer below for some ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an aluminum transition strip from the vinyl to the tile. Some types of transition strips are really intended to be installed under the higher tile layer so this may limit your ability to hide fasteners that secure the strip in place. Here are some examples:

[image]...[image]

[image]

You can normally find an assortment of different styles of aluminum transition strips at hardware stores and big box home centers.

Comment: Often transition strips are too long, but can be cut down easily with a hack saw or chop saw (only with the correct blade)  If you (or your hardware store) do cut it down, make sure to file the edges smooth, otherwise they can get a little sharp.